# Display Image in picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using windows forms C#, I have 2 forms the 1st form contains a menuItem and a pictureBox, when the menuItem is clicked the 2nd form appears. The 2nd form also contains a button, I want when I click the button in the second form, a bitmap image appears in the pictureBox of the 1st form.

this is the menuItem event handler, it's supposed to open the other form and load an image in the pictureBox (when the button in the 2nd form is clicked)

```
  private void imageToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 win = new Form3();
        win.ShowDialog();

        pictureBox1.Image = myNormal.bmp; 
       // displaying.Displaybmp(pictureBox1, b);
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    }
```

'myNormal' is a class which contains bitmap image.

I don't know why the pictureBox doesn't load the image.

Comment: You'll have to add some code, showing what you've done so far and precisely where you're stuck.

Comment: lack of information, code snippet is missing, I suggest to close this question because it is off-topic "unclear! what you are asking"

Comment: Does this code compile? If so: Let us see the class and how you load the Image there, please..

Answer (score 1):

Create the Interface first to invoke the method in form1.

```
public interface IMyForm
{
    void ShowImage(Image image);
}
```

Then implement that interface in your `Form1` and assign the image to the picture box in implemented method `ShowImage(Image)`.

```
public class Form1 : Form, IMyForm
{

    public void ShowImage(Image image)
    {
        this.PictureBox1.Image = image;
    }

    private void menuitem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2()
        frm2.Show(this); //Assign the owner as current form
    }

}
```

Now, write some code to invoke the method in Form1. Create the object of `IMyForm` and assign the value from `this.owner` property.

```
//Form2
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IMyForm frm = (IMyForm)this.owner;
    frm.ShowImage(new Bitmap(@"D:\myImage.jpg"));    
}
```

If you don't wish to you `Form.Show(owner)` method then you can get the available form object in button click event by `Application.OpenForms[]` Form Collection.

```
IMyForm frm = (IMyForm)Application.OpenForms("Form1");
frm.ShowImage(new Bitmap(@"D:\myImage.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample from msdn :

```
private Bitmap MyImage ;
public void ShowMyImage(String fileToDisplay, int xSize, int ySize)
{
   // Sets up an image object to be displayed. 
   if (MyImage != null)
   {
      MyImage.Dispose();
   }

   // Stretches the image to fit the pictureBox.
   pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage ;
   MyImage = new Bitmap(fileToDisplay);
   pictureBox1.ClientSize = new Size(xSize, ySize);
   pictureBox1.Image = (Image) MyImage ;
}
```

looks like you need to also provide value for ClientSize property.

please refer here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox(v=vs.110).aspx